# How to fix construction to add a bool value in a string vector

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the construction to have a bool value in a vector. The split method splits the line "###" and there is a true or false statement in the text file.

[code]

```
if (File.Exists("texter.txt"))
                {
                    var itemSaver = new List<string>();         //Skapa lista där böcker ska sparas

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("texter.txt", Encoding.Default, true))
                    {
                        string item = "";

                        while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            itemSaver.Add(item);
                        }
                        reader.Close();

                        foreach (var a in itemSaver)
                        {
                            string[] vektor = a.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            List.Add(vektor);

                            switch (vektor[3])
                            {
                                case "Novellsamling":
                                    Biblotek.Add(new Novellsamling(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], vektor[3]));
                                    break;
                                case "Roman":
                                    Biblotek.Add(new Roman(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], vektor[3]));
                                    break;
                                case "Tidskrift":
                                    Biblotek.Add(new Tidskrift(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], vektor[3]));
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
[/code]

[code]
public class Bok                      // Class Bok som har tre egenskaper
{
    public string title;       //titel
    public string author;      //Författare
    public string typ;         //Vilken typ
    public bool inne;          //sant eller falskt

    protected Bok(string title, string author, string typ, bool inne)  //declarerar konstruktion i klassen
    {
        this.title = title;      //"this" nyckelordet kallas pekaren som representerar förekomst av en klass eller struktur, pekaren används inom icke-statiska metoder.
        this.author = author;    //Pekaren andvänds även på dolda för att separera fält med parameterar
        this.typ = typ;
        this.inne = inne;
    }

public override string ToString()
    {
        return title + " " + author + " " + typ + " " + inne;
}
    public bool ToString(bool inne)
    {
        return inne;
    }

[/code]
```

Reading from a text file, title, author, type, boolean statement and add the vector to a list. Then ill use random method to pick a random book that is available.

Comment: You need to convert the string "true" or "false" to a boolean.  Use something like this Boolean available = (input == "true") ? true : false;  Current code is converting from a boolean to a string and you need to convert string to boolean.

Comment: It sounds like a few people have inferred what you're asking. But just a suggestion - don't forget to include a question in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Am I to assume that you're getting an error about trying to convert a `string` to a `bool` on this line?:

```
Biblotek.Add(new Novellsamling(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], vektor[3]));
```

The constructor is expecting a `bool`.  But `vektor[3]` is a `string`.  Assuming the input data *can* be parsed into a `bool`, you'd have to parse it.  Something like this:

```
var inne = false;
bool.TryParse(vektor[3], out inne);
Biblotek.Add(new Novellsamling(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], inne));
```

Note that this performs no error checking.  If the value fails to parse, it silently continues with the default value of `false`.  To handle the error, check the return value of `TryParse`:

```
var inne = false;
if (!bool.TryParse(vektor[3], out inne))
{
    // parsing failed, handle the error here
}
else
    Biblotek.Add(new Novellsamling(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], inne));
```

If the value *can't* be directly parsed, then what is the value?  For example, you might have the text values "Y" and "N".  In that case you can make your own make-shift parsing, for example:

```
var inne = vektor[3] == "Y";
Biblotek.Add(new Novellsamling(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], inne));
```

The logic for how you define your true/false values from the string value is up to you, as well as the logic of what to do with values which don't directly match your logic.  (Use a default, throw an error, etc.)  But ultimately you need to derive a `bool` from your `string` and pass that to the constructor.

---

Additionally, this method is an error but is also unnecessary and should be removed entirely:

```
public bool ToString(bool inne)
{
    return inne;
}
```

And the real `ToString` method needs a simple correction to build the returned string:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return title + " " + author + " " + typ + " " + inne.ToString();
}
```

or perhaps even better:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{title} {author} {typ} {inne}";
}
```

Comment: I managed to convention string to bool by writing bool.TryParse (vector [3], bool out inside)) but the problem has been that the vector has three cases. I wrote 3, should be 2